# html5 javascript workflow diagram generator

Tags: javascript, html, workflow, diagram

i am looking for a workflow generator in html5 javascript

i have a system that has several status and those status follows a particular workflow that can be altered by the users.

I looking for a simple framework that will generate a visual representation of the workflow

ex :

- from start to process
- from solution to end or from process to end
- finally from solution to end

Comment: I can recommend to have a look into: https://dev.joget.org/community/display/KBv6/Installation+on+Windows

Comment: Also you can check for this powerful free tool available in Github: https://demo.bpmn.io/new

Comment: i found this one which allow you to generate amazing diagram and export it like html page https://gojs.net/latest/samples/IVRtree.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please go through mxGraph ([www.jgraph.com](https://www.jgraph.com)) , which is HTML5 / JavaScript with fallback for HTML 4 browsers. You can see an example using the technology at [www.draw.io](https://www.draw.io)

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a more sophisticated solution, in a commercial scenario, you might want to consider [yFiles for HTML](http://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml). If your system is very simple, this might be overkill, though, and simpler solutions like [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/) may suffice.

The former library supports all kinds of user interaction and customization thereof, as well provides support for easy integration of your own shapes and visual representations.

For workflow visualization specifically, the automatic layout algorithm implementation of the [Sugiyama Layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing) is helpful when a greater number of workflow items need to be arranged automatically:

[image: Sugiyama example rendering created by yFiles]

In the above image, swimlanes have been added, which are very common in more complex workflow diagrams. The algorithm can arrange the shapes, their connections and the swim lanes automatically. You can see this in action in [this live sample application](http://live.yworks.com/demobrowser/index.html#Business-Process-Models)

*Disclosure*: I work for the company that creates said library. On SO I do not represent my employer, my comments, thoughts and posts are my own.

Answer (score 3):

i've tried several workflow, flowchart and diagramming tools.

I found one which i could then make a workflow diagram, load and save data to and from server.

This has almost all the features that can be used to make workflow diagrams:

1) Rich text inside a rectangle.

2) Ability to customise shapes.

3) Ability to add flow-chart symbols and fix back-end code.

4) Works on Android, iOS, HTML5 browsers.

5) Ability to add different kinds of lines to attach to different shapes and objects.

MIT Licensed.

https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/

Comment: hi this is great could you provide a simpe example

Comment: SVG-Edit is a general purpose HTML5 web-based diagramming tool. 
I'm still coding it and have no roadblocks so far. I did try the other diagramming tools, found them unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

here are my two cent.

If you need a GPL and/or commercial version you can use the Draw2d.org lib.
It is an SDK rater than a ready to use application. In this case an integration 
or customization is possible.

- reading/writing JSON
- writing PNG or GIF
- ...